# Cant get Javascript / Jquery plugin to duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery stock ticker, I cannot duplicate the ticker on the same page. My idea was to create a similar ticker on the same page but with a different list of stocks. It might be as simple as changing a few variable names or I might be running into issues as the API is causing conflictions.

I have spent many hours on it so any advice to get this working would be really helpful.

Attached is a JSfiddle of the ticker I am trying to duplicate. If anyone can duplicate this ticker on the same page but with say only a couple of stocks then this would help me hugely.

JS fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/90s6vd8z/1/

```
var gstock = ["NASDAQ:ASTE", "STO:ATCO-A", "JSE:BEL", "BIT:CNHI", "NYSE:DE", "KRX:042670", "EPA:PIG", "TYO:6305", "KRX:009540", "TYO:5406", "TYO:6301", "TYO:6326", "NYSE:MTU", "NYSE:MTW", "HEL:MEO1V", "VIE:PAL", "STO:SAND", "TYO:6395", "NYSE:TEX", "EBR:VLV", "FRA:WAC", "SHE:000528", "SHA:600031", "SHE:000425",  "HKG:1157", "NYSE:OSK", "OTCMKTS:BZZUY", "NYSE:CX", "ELI:CPR", "LON:CRH", "FRA:HEI", "BCBA:JMIN", "BIT:IT", "EPA:LG", "EPA:SGO", "SWX:SCHN", "EPA:SU", "HKG:1192", "OTCMKTS:WBRBY", "LON:WOS", "ASX:CIM", "ASX:LLC", "TSE:ARE", "ASX:AVJ", "VIE:STR", "SWX:IMPN", "NYSE:KBR", "BME:ACS", "ETR:HOT", "NYSE:FLR", "STO:SKA-B", "EPA:FGR", "TYO:1928", "TYO:1802", "SHA:600170", "TYO:1801", "TYO:1803", "LON:BBY", "KRX:000720", "SHA:600528", "EPA:TEC", "NYSE:JEC", "ETR:GBF", "NYSE:CBI", "BME:FER", "BME:ABG", "BME:FCC", "KRX:006360", "LON:NCC", "BME:ANA", "TSE:SNC", "FRA:1AKA", "LON:JGC", "STO:PEAB-B", "IST:ENKAI", "NYSE:EME", "LON:PFC", "NYSE:DHI", "TYO:1808", "NYSE:LEN", "NYSE:PHM", "JSE:AEG", "TYO:1944", "LON:CLLN", "BME:OHL", "AMS:BOKA", "OTCMKTS:ORSDF", "TYO:1860", "TYO:6366", "TYO:1942", "TYO:1881", "TYO:1722", "NYSE:NVR", "NYSE:TPC", "LON:BDEV", "BME:SCYR", "TYO:1821", "TYO:1893", "TYO:1719", "BME:TRE", "MCX:MSTT", "EPA:NXI", "LON:TW", "VIE:POKS", "JSE:MUR", "HKG:3311", "LON:IRV", "TYO:1861", "AMS:ARCAD", "TYO:1924", "LON:AMFW", "LON:MGNS", "LON:PSN", "TYO:1820", "BIT:AST", "ELI:EGL", "LON:KIE", "EBR:CFEB", "BIT:SAL", "HEL:LEM1S", "AMS:HEIJM", "NYSE:TOL", "NYSE:MDR", "LON:BKG", "TYO:6330", "TYO:1883", "TYO:1720", "STO:ICA", "HEL:YTY1V", "LON:GFRD", "NYSE:GVA", "OTCMKTS:DHOXQ", "LON:KLR", "ELI:TDSA", "NYSE:RYL", "NYSE:KBH", "BIT:MT", "LON:LSR", "IST:TKFEN", "LON:ISG", "TYO:1833", "TYO:1885", "NYSE:SPF", "ETR:B5A", "KRX:005830", "BOM:532693", "NYSE:HOV", "NYSE:MTH", "TYO:1762", "TLV:SKBN", "TPE:9933", "LON:BWY", "OTCMKTS:AGRUF", "TLV:AFIL", "AMS:BALNE", "BIT:TFI", "FRA:HLL", "NSE:HCC", "TYO:1884","TYO:1890", "BKK:ITD", "TYO:1815", "TYO:1852", "LON:COST", "FRA:3GH", "CPH:PAAL-B", "TYO:6960", "TYO:1822", "NYSE:BZH", "BOM:509550", "TYO:1882", "TYO:1811", "NYSE:GFA", "TYO:1805", "FRA:1GT",  "KRX:000800", "WSE:PXM", "LON:RNWH", "CPH:ARKIL-B", "BIT:VLA", "HKG:6210", "HKG:0914", "TYO:5233", "HKG:1893", "HKG:2009", "BIT:IT", "ASX:BLD", "TPE:1101", "NYSE:VMC", "TYO:5232", "NYSE:MLM", "BME:CPL", "HKG:1666", "BKK:SCC"];
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
        $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" + gstock[i] + "&callback=?", function (response) {
            var stockInfo1 = response[0];
            var divContainer = $('*[data-symbol="' + stockInfo1.t + '"]');
            var divCurrency = $('*[data-currency="' + stockInfo1.d + '"]');
            var percentStock = !isNaN(stockInfo1.c) && !isNaN(stockInfo1.l) && stockInfo1.l ? ((parseFloat(stockInfo1.c)/parseFloat(stockInfo1.l)) * 100) : undefined;
            var stockString1 = '<div class="stockWrapper">' + divContainer.data('title') + ':';
            var stockName1 = stockInfo1.t;
            var stockCurency1 = stockInfo1.d;


            var stockPrice2 = "";

            stockPrice2 += '<span class="stockSymbol "> ' + stockInfo1.l + '</span>';



            var stockChange = "";
            stockString1 += '<span class="stockSymbol "> ' + stockInfo1.t + ' </span>';
            if(!isNaN(percentStock) && percentStock > 0) {
                percentStock = Number((percentStock).toFixed(2));
                stockChange += '<span class="stockChange "> ' + percentStock + ' %</span>';
            } else if(!isNaN(percentStock)) {
                percentStock = Number((percentStock).toFixed(2));
                stockChange += '<span class="stockPrice "> ' + percentStock + ' %</span>';
            } else {
                stockChange += '<span class="stockPrice "></span>';
                stockChange += percentage + '% </span>';


            }
            stockString1 += stockChange + '</div>';
            $("#title").append("<div>" + divContainer.data('title') + "</div>");
            $("#symbols").append("<div><b>" + stockInfo1.t + "</b></div>");
          $("#currency").append("<div><b>" + $(divContainer).attr( 'data-currency') + "</b></div>");
            $("#livePrice").append("<div>" + stockPrice2 + "</div>");
            $("#liveData").append("<div>" + stockChange + "</div>");
            divContainer.append(stockString1);

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that jQuery is global, and id's are global as well. You can't make two `div`s with `id=title`. You can use classes.

Comment: Could you show this as a example in the JSfiddle as I am struggling to get this working. regards,

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it is not working is because of your use of `id's` / `#`

There can only be 1 ID per page, and having multiple per page will cause unwanted behavior. In order to create a plugin that can be used multiple times per page you will have to use `classes`.

So - instead of `$('#title')` and `id="title"` change that to `$('.title')` and `class="title"`

Comment: Would it be possible to highlight this in the jsfiddle? Many thanks for your help

Comment: @user3036451 You need to work in the Console. You have an error in your code as well. I would suggest re-evaluate the way you are handling all of this information. I don't think there is a need to hardcode your HTML divs. I would also suggest adding those `divs` based on your `gstock` array using jQuery and have your code control the container with all of the stocks. Or, you could hardcode 1 div and use the `data` tag to tell your jQuery which stocks to populate that div with

Comment: Thanks I will check the console, I will try hardcoding the div and use the data tag / jquery

Comment: Yeah, you can try something like `<div class="stock-ticker" data-stocks="stock pseudos"></div>` and then in your jQuery, pull that data and then use it to append items to that specific stock-ticker

Comment: I'm struggling with this, is there any way you can implement this into the JSfiddle so I can see how it works?